# Make only part of a sentence a link (add selector)

Tags: ios, objective-c

so I am trying to implement the following. I have a view, which has a sentence. Only part of the sentence links to another view. This is what it looks like:

```
I am a cat. Learn More
```

The Learn More would be a link (blue in color), which when clicked would open another view.

Currently I am using a UILabel to write "I am a cat". I realize that the best way to add selectors is to use a button, so "Learn More" should be a button?

Is there any way to write this sentence out without using two different UIComponents?

If not, then how do I make the UILabel and the UIButton completely horizontally aligned with each other?

The following is my code for the label in -layoutSubviews:

```
CGSize labelSize = [_label.text sizeWithFont:_label.font constrainedToSize:bounds.size lineBreakMode:_label.lineBreakMode];
  _label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width - kMarginForText, labelSize.height);
  _label.center = CGPointMake(horizontalCenter, CGRectGetMaxY(_previousLabel.frame) + kDistanceBetweenPreviousAndCurrentLabel);
```

And the code for the label itself.

```
    _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _label.text = "I am a cat";
    _label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _label.numberOfLines = 0;
    _label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    [self addSubview:_label];
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why aren't you using the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about a single UIComponent, you could use a UILabel in conjunction with a UITapGestureRecognizer to create the intended effect. Granted this would make the whole label tappable... but having a bigger tap target area is almost never a bad thing.

In particular you would use an NSAttributedString to set the label text ([NSAttributedString change color at end of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123503/nsattributedstring-change-color-at-end-of-string)):

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
//Use initwithframe or setup your constraints after initialization here
label.attributedText = (your nsattributed string here)
```

Then to initialize the tap recognizer onto the UILabel you would do something like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userDidTapLearnMore)];
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[label addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to align them by their *baselines*, which you can easily do in Interface Builder by selecting them and choosing Editor > Align > Baselines, as shown in this illustration:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But what if I need to do it programmatically?

Comment: Then you would use autolayout. NSLayoutConstraint gives you the power to pin the baseline of one view to that of another.